# Provider store can't be found in the context or props of Connect()

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I keep getting a "could not find 'store' in either the context or props of "Connect(SalesOrderList)" error. I provide the provider store as you can see in my App.js file below. Not sure what the error is coming from. This is my first attempt at integrating redux with react-native and I'm having trouble hooking everything together. Anyone with experience please help. Thanks =)

My App.js

```
const store = createStore(reducers, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && 
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(), applyMiddleware(Thunk));

console.log(store.getState());

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  state = { loggedIn: null};

  renderView() {
    switch (this.state.loggedIn) {
      case true:
        return <AppNavigator />
      case false:
        return <Login />;
      default:
        return <AppNavigator />;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {this.renderView()}
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Index.ios.js

```
    import {
      AppRegistry,
    } from 'react-native';
    import App from './src/components/App';
    import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
    import SalesOrderList from './src/components/SalesOrderList';
    import SalesOrderItem from './src/components/SalesOrderItem';

    const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
      SalesOrderList : { screen: SalesOrderList },
      SalesOrderItem : { screen: SalesOrderItem }
    });

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('issicrm', () => AppNavigator);

    export default AppNavigator;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are registering the `AppNavigator` component in your index.ios.js: 
`AppRegistry.registerComponent('issicrm', () => AppNavigator);`.

If you look closely, the `AppNavigator` component you are linking is just a StackNavigator component, it is not connected to your Redux store at all, this why you are seeing the error within the `SalesOrderList` component's connect call.

I think you probably wanted to register your `App` component in your index.ios.js, because you imported it but have never used it.

Comment: Thanks man! I"ll try that tomorrow morning and let you know how it goes.

Comment: That fixed my store issue now but now I'm getting a blank screen... I think it has to do with my AppNavigator.js or App.js. From what I remember you need to AppRegistry.registerComponent('issicrm', () => AppNavigator); for navigation to work.. correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @EricHan, is hard for other people to help you with this new issue without knowing more how you setup your app. I would suggest you to open up a new question for the blank screen issue and accept this answer if this has helped you solved your original problem.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I decided not to use redux with my application.